# multi dimension json parse in php

Tags: php, json

I have below data while form submit.

```
{
"formData":[
        {"id":"choice1","name":"Test"},
        {"id":"choice2","name":"Test2"}
        ],
 "uid":"75"
}
```

I need to parse it in php backend file.

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

$request = json_decode($postdata);

$formData = $request->formData;

$uid = $request->uid;
```

I can get uid data properly but i am not sure how to get others.

Any advise on this?

Comment: Isn't it $request->formData[0]->id ?

Comment: formdata can go till 10. Do i need to use loop for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
foreach($request->formData as $data) {
  echo $data->id;
  //Do any other operations with each element...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. let me try this. Voted up.

Comment: how can i assign it to dynamic variable. instead of echo i am trying like this 'value'.$i = $data.id where $i is 1234 coming from the loop.